# Visual Studio 2019 Auto-format not working as of 16.5.4

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I just upgraded VS2019 on Windows to version 16.5.4, and the text editor auto-formatting is no longer working.

For all previous version of Visual Studio (at least when editing .vb files), when you hit enter at the end of a line, that line would get auto-formatted.

For example, let's say you had this line of code:

```
Dim Test as string = ""
```

if you hit enter at the end of that line, Visual Studio would change `string` to `String` automatically.  That functionality is no longer working.

Has anyone else seen this?  Does anyone know how to fix it?  Is it a bug with VS?

Comment: Can you clarify that in Tools-Options-Text Editor-Basic-Advanced, under Editor Help, the Pretty Listing is enabled? If so, try https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ClearMEFComponentCache

Comment: How can I most efficiently send you all of my money?  Wire transfer? Venmo?  I shall send you all of the monies.  Every single one.  Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you!!!  (The setting was off.  I turned it on, and the desired functionality is working again)

Comment: Feel free to create an answer, will help anyone who stumbled upon it

Answer (score 6):

Go to Tools...Options...Text Editor...Basic...Advanced...Editor Help -> ensure Pretty Listing is enabled.

Thank you to [@Martheen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529282/martheen)

Comment: I had to enable code cleanup on save under Code Cleanup.